# Recursive route calling possible in ember.js?

Tags: recursion, ember.js

I have one route that I have to call inside loop from another controller, see for example.

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++)
{
       this.transitionToRoute("another_route");
}
```

I have tried this but not calling multiple times this route. Only when i=10 at that time this route is able transition.

Comment: What is your intention? I don;t understand why would you want to transition inside a loop?

Comment: Hi... @Asgaroth......For multiple call, Actually problem is different, But for now please tell me it is possible or not ?

Comment: Plain and simple, It does not make sense.